# Wordpress .htaccess file dont work with apach2

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I dont know if this should be here or in askubunt.

I think my problem lays with the wordpress permalinks. I can visit the frontpage, but no images works and when I try to visit any links. I get a 404 error.

But it seems that apache2 cant really read my wordpress .htaccess file. Which looks like:

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
# End Error

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have made the right privilige to all my wordpress files like such:

> set permission for .htaccess 644. Set permissions on all directories to 755: `find . -type d -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;` Set permissions on all files to 644: `find . -type f -print -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

I thought first that it was my apache2 config file or `mysite.com.conf` file that was at fault, but they seems to be correct. Looks like:

```
myste.com.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/mysite
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/mysite">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


apache2 conf file (relevant)

<Directory /home/mysite>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So it seems like everything should be in order.

Also when I try to enable rewrite `a2enmod rewrite` I get a 500 server error when trying to visit site.

What could be the problem? All problems i found like this was that they either didnt have the `AllowOverride All` or that that there wordpress .htaccess file was wrong. But this seems not to be the case.

What should I do?

Comment: What does Apache's error log say when the '500' error occurs? The `rewrite` module should be enabled for the rewrites to work, but it's possible some other rewrite rules could cause a redirect loop.(Especially if there are multiple .htaccess files, or if there are other rewrite rules in your .htaccess file above that aren't shown here.)

Comment: @Matt Ok, wierd. I did `sudo a2enmod rewrite` now and now I dont get the error. The site is still the same(not working) but I dont get errors. Yes I did restart apache after :)

Answer (score 0):

There are errors on your .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
....
```